# Java timer issue

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener

I have a applet that simulates a coffee vending machine. I am trying to get the text Ready to be display for 5 secs. But it doesn't seem to be working. can anyone tell me what's wrong with my timer ?

Class qn1 is the class for JApplet.
init() will be called to instantiate the variables.

I add actionlistener to the 2 buttons so they will react when i click them.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;

    public class qn1 extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

        private static int FULL = 4;
        private int coffees = FULL;
        private JPanel p;
        private JButton jbtw, jbtb;
        private Dispenser dis;
        private JLabel jlbl;
        private Timer timer;

        public void init() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
            setSize(400, 500);

            p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
            jbtw = new JButton("White");
            jbtb = new JButton("Black");
            jbtw.addActionListener(this);
            jbtb.addActionListener(this);
            p.add(jbtw);
            p.add(jbtb);

            add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            dis = new Dispenser();
            add(dis, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            jlbl = new JLabel("Select", SwingConstants.CENTER);
            add(jlbl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            timer = new Timer(50, this);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource().equals(jbtb) | e.getSource().equals(jbtw)) {
                if (coffees - 1 >= 0) {
                    coffees--;
                    jlbl.setText("Ready " + coffees);               
                }

                timer.setInitialDelay(5000);
                timer.start();  

                if (coffees == 0) {
                    jlbl.setText("Empty");
                } else {
                    jlbl.setText("Select" + coffees);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Dispenser extends JPanel {
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, 25, 50);
            g.drawLine(25, 50, 55, 50);
            g.drawLine(55, 50, 80, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timer is called, but if the source is not one of your button, you don't perform anything:

```
    if (e.getSource().equals(jbtb) | e.getSource().equals(jbtw)) {
```

To answer your comments, you might want something like that:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(jbtb) | e.getSource().equals(jbtw)) {
            timer.setInitialDelay(5000);
            timer.start();  

            if (coffees == 0) {
                jlbl.setText("Empty");
            } else {
                jlbl.setText("Select " + coffees);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (coffees - 1 >= 0) {
                coffees--;
                jlbl.setText("Ready " + coffees);               
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @xinwei Single stepping through this in debug mode would have helped you find this--you might want to get used to it (if you are not using Eclipse or Netbeans, START!)

Comment: I tried remove the if (e.getSource().equals(jbtb) | e.getSource().equals(jbtw)) { but it doesn't work. 
I add that statement beacuse the button and the timer both shared the same source listener, so i though i should differentiate the source in the code.

Comment: You should. But think what do you want to do if the timer called the listener? Also, note that you set the text in the label right after setting it to `ready`.

Comment: I try in debug mode, it did step into the statement jlbl.setText("Ready " + coffees);      but it didn't stay for 5 seconds

Comment: i add the statement  if (e.getSource().equals(timer)) {
 jlbl.setText("Ready " + coffees); } but it doesn't work

Comment: I find it much more readable and less error-prone to use a separate listener for each of the events I'm handling. In this case using anonymous inner classes, but usually named ones. Also, that allows me to remove "implements ActionListener" from qn1. Outsiders should probably not have access to actionPerformed.

Comment: @jackrabbit I agree with you, it was my mistake not to separate those listeners, as they should be.